# Qt can't connect a subclass of QGraphicsView signal (not inherited) to SLOT

Tags: qt, signals-slots, qgraphicsview

I defined class MyGraphicsView, a subclass of QGraphicsView. Than, I add a signal test() in MyGraphicsView. In my MainWindow class, I have MyGraphicsView* myView and I connect like:

connect(myView, SIGNAL( test() ) , this, SLOT( zoom() )) ;

But I got:

```
    QObject::connect: No such signal QGraphicsView::test() in ..\Proto_version_2\mainwindow.cpp:73
```

Comment: Can we see your code?

Comment: Did you add Q_OBJECT in your `MyGraphicsView` declaration?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to use slots and signals in a class, it must be derived from either QObject or a QObject derived class and your class must include the Q_OBJECT macro

```
class MyClass : public QGraphicsView
{
    Q_OBJECT // Without this macro, signals and slots will not work

    public:
        MyClass(QObject* parent);
};
```

The Q_OBJECT macro allows classes to use QT's C++ extensions. As the documentation states: -

> The Meta-Object Compiler, moc, is the program that handles Qt's C++ extensions.
>   The moc tool reads a C++ header file. If it finds one or more class declarations that contain the Q_OBJECT macro, it produces a C++ source file containing the meta-object code for those classes. Among other things, meta-object code is required for the signals and slots mechanism, the run-time type information, and the dynamic property system.

Note, however that Qt 5 provides an additional connect call, which warns if the Q_OBJECT is missing: -

```
connect(myView, QMainView::test, myClassObj, MyClass::zoom);
```

In this case, the 2nd and 4th argument are pointers to the functions. In addition, run-time checking of the connect call is performed. You can read more about this [here](http://qt-project.org/wiki/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax).

Comment: `moc` is *always needed* whether you use the old or the new syntax. The Qt 5 `connect` will not even compile if you attempt connection to an object without the `Q_OBJECT` macro.

Comment: @KubaOber, Oops my mistake. I was writing that in a rush. I've corrected the answer.