# Undefined reference to signal in QT

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I wanted to create a class in an separate file in Qt and then use this class in my main file (Background: Secondary thread updating GUI). Thus I wrote `ReadDPC.h`-file:

```
class ReadDPC: public QThread
{
//First edit:
Q_OBJECT
//End of first edit
public:
    void run();
signals:
    void currentCount(int);
};
```

And in my `ReadDPC.cpp`-file:

```
void ReadDPC::run()
{
    while(1)
    {
        usleep(50);
        int counts = read_DPC();
        emit currentCount(counts);
    }
}
```

`read_DPC()` is a function returning an `int`-value also placed in the cpp-file.
But when I want to compile this, I get the error `undefined reference to ReadDPC::currentCount(int)`. Why? How can I solve this?

Edit: Added `Q_Object`-Macro, no solution.

Comment: There's an explanation here for what's required in using signals and slots: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22985894/qt-cant-connect-a-subclass-of-qgraphicsview-signal-not-inherited-to-slot/22986102#22986102

Comment: Also note that inheriting from QThread isn't recommended for using threads: http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2010/06/17/youre-doing-it-wrong/

Comment: And also you can read this article: http://woboq.com/blog/qthread-you-were-not-doing-so-wrong.html

Comment: After adding Q_OBJECT macro, you must run qmake before Building

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Add Q_OBJECT macro to your subclass and run qmake.

This macro allows you use signals and slots mechanism. Without this macro moc can't create your signal so you get error that your signal is not exist.

Code should be:

```
class ReadDPC: public QThread {
Q_OBJECT
```

Note that when you use new signal and slot syntax, you can get compile time error that you forgot add this macro. If it is interesting for you, read more here: http://qt-project.org/wiki/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax

Comment: @arc_lupus try clean your project and rebuild it.

Comment: Cleaned the project, rebuild it, no change :-(. Did I forgot to add some additional header files?

Comment: @arc_lupus same issue: op just run qmake: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25470635/qconnect-find-no-such-slot-on-qcombobox-by-qt-creater/25470865#25470865

Comment: Did you run `moc` on the header and include the resulting `.cpp` file in your project (compile/link)?

Comment: No, I only ran qmake.

Answer (score 7):

1. add Q_OBJECT
2. Clear your project
3. Run qmake
4. And only after that, run your project

Answer (score 4):

When you are going to use Qt signals & slots mechanism you have to add `Q_OBJECT` macro in the top of definition of your class in order to generate correct `moc_` code.

### Why is this so?

> The Meta-Object Compiler, moc, is the program that handles Qt's C++
>   extensions.
>
> The moc tool reads a C++ header file. If it finds one or more class
>   declarations that contain the Q_OBJECT macro, it produces a C++ source
>   file containing the meta-object code for those classes. Among other
>   things, meta-object code is required for the signals and slots
>   mechanism, the run-time type information, and the dynamic property
>   system.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/moc.html#moc